# Adding colour to individual tagged cells in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Basically I'm building an iOS app which allows users to track their moods throughout the month so that they can evaluate when they are most stressed and when they are most happy.

Each day, users can write a block of information about the day and colour code each day so that in a list view they can quickly see how the month is going (for example, if most of the month is red then it indicates that they are having a bad month).

I am using green, amber, and red to identify the moods of users. But I'm having trouble making each individual cell the colour that the user has selected. I have given each colour cell a tag to identify the user's choice. I'm just having trouble actually calling the function to allow it to be displayed on the screen.

This is the code in my list view controller:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell")!

    let post = posts[indexPath.row]

    let cellTitle = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
    cellTitle.text = post.title

    let cellText = cell.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel
    cellText.text = post.text

    return cell
}
```

I know that I need to call the functions, but how do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor() // or any other color depending on the tag
}
```

Comment: thank you, but (and i may be being stupid here) is the first block of code going? I cannot find tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath??

Comment: you need to add that method to your class, check my edit

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you want to modify the color of specific cell in the table view. The simplest solution is to modify the cell in your function which is required for the table view anyways.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
}
```

After you specify which cell you want to edit using indexPath use `cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.yourColor()` to change the background.